# How add a record in a collection with rails console?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i have this :

```
 Order.find(19).order_items

 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

how can i add this object "order_item" to "Order"?

```
order_item = OderItem.find(2)
```

Comment: Please read "[ask]", including the links at the bottom, and "[mcve]". Your example is not syntactically correct, plus your grammar needs work. Please take the time to capitalize correctly as the effort you put into your question will be reflected by the effort others will put into helping you.

Answer (score 2):

There is your answer :

```
 Order.find(19).order_items << OrderItem.find(2)
```

After reading some comments, let me improve my answer by adding this link :
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference
You can look at the 4.3.1.2 collection<<(object, ...) point

Comment: If this answer solves the problem, then show your appreciation by upvoting the answer and selecting the best answer as the solution to the problem. It's good to wait a day before selecting a solution though, as good answers often take a while to formulate, and the earth, having 24 hours/day, causes some answerers to not see the question for 12 hours or more.

Comment: Instead of tossing out code, explain _why_ the code is appropriate. It's the difference between handing someone who's starving a fish vs. teaching them how to fish.